# How can I format a string with a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a list of data

`data= ['Mom','Dad',1,'Dog','World']`

I want to format another string with these strings, but I want the formatting to be so that if the element in `data` is a string then it should be surrounded by quotes.  I could use flow control, but would rather just use string formatting instead.

For instance, the desired output would be something like

```
You are my 'Mom'
You are my 'Dad'
You are my 1 #Notice that the 1 is an int and is not surrounded by quotes
You are my 'Dog'
You are my 'World'
```

Is there a way to format that?

Comment: Do you know how to iterate the data? Do you know how to check what data type a value is?

Comment: @takendarkk yes and yes, but flow control is not what I want to do.  I am curious if I can accomplish it with formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `!r` format conversion specifier:

```
>>> data= ['Mom','Dad',1,'Dog','World']
>>> for item in data:
...     print('you are my {!r}'.format(item))
... 
you are my 'Mom'
you are my 'Dad'
you are my 1
you are my 'Dog'
you are my 'World'
```

This formats using `__repr__` rather than `__str__` (which is the default).  Since `str.__repr__` adds the quotes, it works out how you expect.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach just to make up for my previous misinterpretation of the question (really is just a variation of @mgilsons approach):

```
fmt = "You are my {!r}"
print(*map(fmt.format, data), sep='\n')
```

which prints out the wanted result.

Comment: In my question, I specify that if the data is a string, then it should have quotes.

Comment: Quite embarrassed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Though more verbose, a simple if statement should work

```
data= ['Mom','Dad',1,'Dog','World']

for d in data:
    print("You are my {}".format("'{}'".format(d) if isinstance(d, str) else d))
```

Output

```
You are my 'Mom'
You are my 'Dad'
You are my 1
You are my 'Dog'
You are my 'World'
```

Comment: I thought of this too, but wanted to avoid if-else statements because of the verbosity.  Thanks